# PCA with covariance matrix calculated using random matrix theory in R

Tags: r, pca, random-matrix

I would like to perform a PCA and use the covariance matrix obtained by the [random matrix theory](http://www.math.nyu.edu/fellows_fin_math/gatheral/RandomMatrixCovariance2008.pdf).

Is there an implementation of this in R?

I am currently using the standard *prcomp* function from **stats**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [**tawny** package](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/tawny/html/tawny-package.html). I don't think it has a function to do just plain PCA with the random matrix theory covariance matrix, but you might be able to find the code to generate the relevant covariance matrix and plug that into `princomp()` using argument `covmat`.